# Twisted makeService() async

Tags: python, asynchronous, plugins, twisted

I need to create a `MultiService` that loads asynchronously in a twisted plugin, is there a way of achieving that ?

Here what I've done so far:

**app/plugins.py**

```
class Options(usage.Options):
    synopsis = '[options]'
    longdesc = (
        'Starts app modules services. The modules must '
        'be configured and enabled for the current server '
        'before being started. To see the list installed modules '
        'use the --list switch.')
    optFlags = [['list', 'l', 'Display the list of installed modules.']]


def makeService(options):
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    debug = options['debug']
    return app.ModuleService.load(reactor)
```

**twisted/plugins/app_plugins.py**

```
TestService = ServiceMaker(
    'test',
    'app.plugins',
    'Test service.',
    'test')
```

**app.py**

```
class ModuleService(service.MultiService):
    def __init__(self, reactor=None):

        # Twisted old style classes
        service.MultiService.__init__(self)

        if reactor is None:
            from twisted.internet import reactor
        self._reactor = reactor

    @classmethod
    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def load(cls, reactor=None):

        modules = yield get_modules()

        service = cls(reactor)

        for module in modules:
            # module tcp server
            mod_endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, module.port)
            module_service = internet.StreamServerEndpointService(
                mod_endpoint,
                pb.PBServerFactory(spread.RunnerServer()))
            module_service.setServiceParent(service)

        defer.returnValue(service)
```

So my problem is that the MultiService is loaded asynchronously and therefore cannot be used in the `makeService` function, someone can help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Services in twisted are not supposed to start asynchronously. Service start is done before reactoru startup. You should change your application architecture. I am currently studying how :D